# How can I make the quizView appear in green onTapGesture when the user clicks the right answer

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am making a language app and want the correct answer to appear in green once the user taps on it but I am struggling to do so.

This is the part of the code where I want to achieve this behavior.

[image]

```
            Grid(viewModel.answers) { answer in
                
                //how can i change the ui of quizView(answer) that is being tapped inside the closure
                quizView(answer: answer).onTapGesture {
                    if self.viewModel.chooseAnswer(answer: answer){
                        self.dim.toggle()
                        self.disabled.toggle()
                        print("a")
                        
                    }
                }
                .opacity(self.dim ? 0.4 : 1.0)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
                .disabled(self.disabled)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top])
    }
}}

struct quizView: View {
var answer: LearnModel.Answer

var body: some View{
    

    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack{

            answerBubble
            Text(self.answer.word.EnglishWord)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    }
}}
var answerBubble: some View {
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
    .fill(Color.black)
    .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 20, y: 5)
    .opacity(0.2)
    .padding()
}
```

**Grid(viewModel.answers)** - Creates the Grid and Gridlayout for the answer bubbles.

**Screenshot of the UI**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `answerBubble` is the view that you're trying to update. So, this view needs to have some type of parameter that changes its fill color.

Let's assume that the background turns green if the user taps the right answer, keeps its black color if it isn't tapped, and turns red otherwise. I would create a stateful list of tapped answers in your main view:

`@State private var tappedAnswers = [LearnModel.Answer]()`

This will create an empty list of answers that you can keep track of. Once the user taps the `quizView`, then you should add it to the list if it isn't there already (you could really do this with a `Set`, but I'm sticking with arrays for its familiarity).

```
quizView(answer: answer).onTapGesture {
    // Add the new answer to the list of tapped answers
    if !tappedAnswers.contains(answer) {
        tappedAnswers.append(answer)
    }
    // Do any animation work you need in here
}
```

I'm not familiar with the rest of your application, but you need to store the correct answer and compare that to the selected answers. We'll call this `correctAnswer` for now.

Now you can add a function that determines the appropriate fill color for each `answerBubble`:

```
func colorFor(answer: LearnModel.Answer, correctAnswer: LearnModel.Answer) -> Color {

   if answer == correctAnswer {
       // Check for correct answer right away; order matters here.
       return Color.green
   } else if tappedAnswers.contains(correctAnswer) {
       // The user tapped the answer, but it wasn't correct.
       return Color.red
   } else {
       // The user hasn't tapped this answer yet.
       return Color.black
   }

}
```

Finally, add a parameter to `answerBubble` that accepts a `fillColor` variable that lets you pass in this newly created color method (although you'll need to make this a proper SwiftUI view).

```
struct AnswerBubble: View {

    let fillColor: Color

    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .fill(fillColor)
            .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 20, y: 5)
            .opacity(0.2)
            .padding()
    }

}
```

Also make sure that you pass the `fillColor` you get to `quizView` since it needs to pass it to `answerBubble`. Now you can use this inside your `ForEach` loop. Once you've added the parameters, it should look like:

```
quizView(
    answer: answer, 
    fillColor: self.colorFor(
        answer: answer, 
        correctAnswer: correctAnswer
    )
)
```

(Also, consider renaming `quizView` to `QuizView` since it's not a variable)

I don't know the details of your `LearnModel`, but you should be able to adapt this as you need.